# Pause program until key is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have made some script in c# and my need is to pause script until user press any key. I need many pauses of this type in my program, so making event for every single is realy boring. Is any way, how you can pause app until key is pressed? Something like `Console.ReadKey()` in console application?

```
//some kind of running code
//------------------
//pause until key is pressed
//-------------------
//code running after key press
```

Comment: write Console.Read() at this place //pause until key is pressed

Comment: i already tried, but program not wait, only skips console.write and continue

Comment: what kind of program is that? WPF, WinForms, some DSL?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense, a WPF app uses a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tags suggest this is a WPF application without a console. If you just need to detect a key press, you could override the `KeyDown` event.

```
<Window KeyDown="OnKeyDown" />
```

Then

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // signal your activity to continue
}
```